# Writing binary files in Python 2.6+ and 3

Tags: python, binary, io, python-3.x

I am writing a program that needs to write a binary file. In contains a header of strings (key-value pairs) and numeric data (which can be little-endian or big-endian) and I am looking for a way to write a program that runs unchanged in Python 2.6+ and Python 3.2+.

Can anyone suggest some best practices? Additionally, what is the right way to deal with endianness without cluttering the logic of my program with `struct.pack`. Should I subclass `BufferedWriter`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's easier to code for Python3 and then see what breaks for Python2. It's a pain to write for both at once (at least for me).

Comment: If you're writing numeric data to a binary file, why would you avoid the use of `struct.pack`? It's designed for that task. Would you avoid using a hammer when driving nails into wood?

Comment: It would help considerably if you gave us a pointer to the actual layout, otherwise you will need to say what a "string" is (ASCII, UTF-8, something else; how is length determined) and what "numeric data" is (float (size?), int (signed/unsigned? size?), other),is there one endian-ness flag per file or per data item.

Answer (score 1):

Once you created the binary data, you just write it to a file opened in binary mode. That's all there is to it. No compatibility problems between Python 2 and 3 there at all.

Subclassing BufferedWriter is completely unecessary.

How you create the data is a different question, but again there I don't see any obvious incompatibility problems.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I still need to put the data in some type of buffer and therefore my problems remain.

Comment: @Hernan: Why do you need to put the data in some kind of buffer? Normally a bytes() string works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you already have a predefined binary file format that you need to match, but if not and you are just trying to serialize your data structures in a way that can be read by multiple programming languages (as well as multiple Python versions on multiple platforms), you may want to look at [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.open + os.write + os.close.  However, these need while loops for reliability.

I've done this using http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/bufsock.html (I wrote it, my former employer allowed me to opensource it) to achieve this in a deduplicating backup program that does lots of binary I/O.  Doing it this way doesn't require loops, even if you're employing signals.  Don't let the "bufsock" name fool you - it's also good for file I/O.

BTW, writing stuff in an endian-dependent way is usually a mistake in the long term.  If you're not content with the builtin Python tools (I'm not always, EG once I needed a 3 byte integer type), it's probablty better to tear apart your numbers using divmod 256.  Another alternative is to use http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/base255.html to get null-terminateable strings.

Comment: The endianness problem is something that I need to do as it depends on the specification. I will look at your code, thanks!